# sqlalchemy query using joinedload exponentially slower with each new filter clause

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this sqlalchemy query:

```
query = session.query(Store).options(joinedload('salesmen').
                                        joinedload('comissions').
                                        joinedload('orders')).\
        filter(Store.store_code.in_(selected_stores))

stores = query.all()
for store in stores:
    for salesman in store.salesmen:
        for comission in salesman.comissions:
            #generate html for comissions for each salesman in each store

#print html document using PySide
```

This was working perfectly, however I added two new filter queries:

```
        filter(Comissions.payment_status == 0).\
        filter(Order.order_date <= self.dateEdit.date().toPython())
```

If I add just the first filter the application hangs for a couple of seconds, if I add both the application hangs indefinitely

What am I doing wrong here? How do I make this query fast?

Thank you for your help

EDIT: This is the sql generated, unfortunately the class and variable names are in Portuguese, I just translated them to English so it would be easier to undertand,
so Loja = Store, Vendedores = Salesmen, Pedido = Order, Comission = Comissao

Query generated:

```
SELECT "Loja"."CodLoja", "Vendedores_1"."CodVendedor", "Vendedores_1"."NomeVendedor", "Vendedores_1"."CodLoja", "Vendedores_1"."PercentualComissao", 
"Vendedores_1"."Ativo", "Comissao_1"."CodComissao", "Comissao_1"."CodVendedor", "Comissao_1"."CodPedido", 
"Pedidos_1"."CodPedido", "Pedidos_1"."CodLoja", "Pedidos_1"."CodCliente", "Pedidos_1"."NomeCliente", "Pedidos_1"."EnderecoCliente", "Pedidos_1"."BairroCliente", 
"Pedidos_1"."CidadeCliente", "Pedidos_1"."UFCliente", "Pedidos_1"."CEPCliente", "Pedidos_1"."FoneCliente", "Pedidos_1"."Fone2Cliente", "Pedidos_1"."PontoReferenciaCliente",
 "Pedidos_1"."DataPedido", "Pedidos_1"."ValorProdutos", "Pedidos_1"."ValorCreditoTroca", 
"Pedidos_1"."ValorTotalDoPedido", "Pedidos_1"."Situacao", "Pedidos_1"."Vendeu_Teflon", "Pedidos_1"."ValorTotalTeflon", 
"Pedidos_1"."DataVenda", "Pedidos_1"."CodVendedor", "Pedidos_1"."TipoVenda", "Comissao_1"."Valor", "Comissao_1"."DataPagamento", "Comissao_1"."StatusPagamento" 
FROM "Comissao", "Pedidos", "Loja" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Vendedores" AS "Vendedores_1" ON "Loja"."CodLoja" = "Vendedores_1"."CodLoja" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Comissao" AS "Comissao_1" ON "Vendedores_1"."CodVendedor" = "Comissao_1"."CodVendedor" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Pedidos" AS "Pedidos_1" ON "Pedidos_1"."CodPedido" = "Comissao_1"."CodPedido" 
WHERE "Loja"."CodLoja" IN (:CodLoja_1) AND "Comissao"."StatusPagamento" = :StatusPagamento_1 AND "Pedidos"."DataPedido" <= :DataPedido_1
```

Comment: What does the SQL look like? You can view it by printing out str(query.statement.compile())

Comment: @MattiJohn Just added the query. Does that help? I can post whatever info you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `FROM` clause is producing a Cartesian product and includes each table twice, once for filtering the result and once for eagerly loading the relationship.

To stop this use [contains_eager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) instead of joinedload in your options. This will look for the related attributes in the query's columns instead of constructing an extra join. You will also need to explicitly join to the other tables in your query, e.g.:

```
query = session.query(Store)\
               .join(Store.salesmen)\   
               .join(Store.commissions)\    
               .join(Store.orders)\     
               .options(contains_eager('salesmen'),
                        contains_eager('comissions'),
                        contains_eager('orders'))\
               .filter(Store.store_code.in_(selected_stores))\
               .filter(Comissions.payment_status == 0)\
               .filter(Order.order_date <= self.dateEdit.date().toPython())
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matti, with a few modifications it worked perfectly!